# Breadth first search with a twist

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

Given a binary matrix where 0's represent obstacle and 1's represent a path, find the minimum number of steps to reach from a given source to a destination (traversal allowed in 4 directions only). This is a typical BFS question.

Source: (0,0) Destination: (2,0)

`1 1 0
 0 1 1
 1 1 1`

Answer: 5

However the next part of this question is tricky, you are allowed to turn a zero into a one with a magic wand. Now how will you find the shortest path in this condition.

If we flip (1,0) we can get to destination with 3 steps.

A typical brute force solution is to do a BFS on every matrix by changing a zero into a one. How can we do better?

This was asked in one of the popular companies.. Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I thought of:

For simplicity, I will treat the matrix as a graph.

So, denote the start position as `s` (vertice) and the destination as `d` 
 (vertice).

Now, we will run BFS once with source `s` and once with source `d`.

So we have for each vertice `v` the minimal distance from `s` to `v` and the minimal distance from `v` to `d` (distance can be infinity, for example all vertices with value 0 in the matrix are with distance infinity).

Now, for each vertice `v` with value `0` in the matrix, do the following:

for each pair of neighbors of `v` (in the matrix, max 4) WHERE THE ORDER MATTERS, that means, the pair of vertices `a` and `b` are different from `b` and `a`.

There are maximum of 4!/2! = 12 pairs.

Denote the pair of vertices `a` and `b` and calculate the following distance:

s->a + 1 + 1 + b->d (s->a, b->d is given, this is the distance for the path s->a->v->b->d).

Pick the minimum from those distances  (max 12 of those) and this is the minimum distance from `s` to `d` with `v` flipped.

Now, you can know which one to flip, and also the minimum distance.

Complexity = O(`V` + `E`)

EDIT:

If the matrix is of `n` x `n` size , then `V` = `n ^ 2` and as each vertice has at most 4 edges then `E` = `O(n^2)` => `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: Hi Asaf. BFS from source node `only` will not give us the shortest path between all nodes. So we have minimal distance only from s to v and not from v to d. For that we need to do BFS on every node pushing it to O(V(V+E)).. Any ideas?

Comment: We didn't run BFS from source only. We ran once from s and one from d.  The first scan will indeed give us only the distance to s but the second one will give us from d. (Which is same like distance to d)

Comment: Ok. that explains. Nice logic!